# How to use multiple UNION in same table

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, union

I am having trouble while fetching data from results table in HTML TABLE form. I have a table results which contains information about students results where marks column having multiple value like *SA1, SA2, SA3, Mid_term, Final*.
So here in this query i am fetching `first_name` and `marks` from `results table`.
The problem is i am getting all marks under `SA1 column` but i want `SA1 marks` under `SA1 Column SA2 marks` under `SA2 Column SA3 marks` under `SA3 Column`.
I tried almost everything but i am unable to figure out what mistake am i doing.

Here is my **code**

```
echo '<table class = "w3-table">
<tr> 
<td> Name </td>
<td> SA1 </td>
<td> SA2 </td>
<td> SA3 </td>
<td> Mid-term </td>
<td> Final </td>
</tr>
<tr>
';
$q = "(SELECT first_name, marks  FROM results WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND 
subject = 'Arts' AND exam_type = 'SA1' )
     UNION ALL (SELECT  NULL, marks as m1  
FROM results WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND subject = 'Arts' 
AND exam_type = 'SA2' ) 
     UNION ALL (SELECT  NULL, marks as m2  FROM results
 WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND subject = 'Arts' AND exam_type = 'SA3' )
     UNION ALL (SELECT  NULL, marks as m3  FROM results 
WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND subject = 'Arts' AND exam_type = 'Mid-term')
     UNION ALL (SELECT  NULL, marks as m4  FROM results 
WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND subject = 'Arts' AND exam_type = 'Final')";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)
or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r))
{
    $name = $row['first_name'];
    $marks = $row['marks'];
    $marks1 = $row['m1'];
    $marks2 = $row['m2'];
    $marks3 = $row['m3'];
    $marks4 = $row['m4'];
    echo '<tr>
         <td>' .$name .'</td>
         <td>'. $marks. '</td>
         <td>'. $marks1. '</td>
         <td>'. $marks2. '</td>
         <td>'. $marks3. '</td>
         <td>'. $marks4. '</td>
         </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: please give your table structure

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a pivot, not a union. Have a look at e.g. [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Comment: id, username, first_name, last_name, exam_type, subject, date, marks, total_marks, class these are columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use mySql **WHEN CASE** to get your desired out put.
Try this

```
SELECT first_name,
case when exam_type = 'SA1' then marks end as m1,  
case when exam_type = 'SA2' then marks end as m2,
case when exam_type = 'SA3' then marks end as m3, 
case when exam_type = 'Mid-term' then marks end as m4,  
case when exam_type = 'Final' then marks end as m5 
FROM results
WHERE class = '11th Arts' AND 
subject = 'Arts'
```

You will get out put as

```
$name = $row['first_name'];
$marks = $row['m1'];
$marks1 = $row['m2'];
$marks2 = $row['m3'];
$marks3 = $row['m4'];
$marks4 = $row['m5'];
```

I thing it will help you.

Comment: Hi i did tried this one before as well the problem was here that first name will keep repeating and marks columns will be not in right place.

Comment: According to your DB structure, you are storing user data in multiple row that's why you will get data in this structure but you can manage the data according to desired format.